# String replace in a text file

Tags: python, string-matching

i have one text file (.txt),with multiple scenario i want to replace the value which is in "< >" with | under the Examples.

When user enters the username "< username >" and password  "< password >"

When user enters the phonenumber "< phone >"

When user enters pincode "< code >"

when user enters filghtnumber "< flight >"

Examples:

| username | password |phone|code| flight|

| john@123 | 789_456 |4556789|33456|ACH003|

When user enters the username "< username >" and password "< password >"

When user enters the phonenumber "< phone >"

When user enters pincode "< code >"

when user enters filghtnumber "< flight >"

Examples:

| username | password |phone|code| flight|

|David@2356 | two_003 |67904578|0337654|IG607|

**i want my data looks like this**

When user enters the username "john@123" and password  "789_456 "

When user enters the phonenumber "4556789"

When user enters pincode "33456"

when user enters filghtnumber "ACH003"

When user enters the username "David@2356" and password "two_003"

When user enters the phonenumber "67904578"

When user enters pincode "0337654"

when user enters filghtnumber "IG607"

i tried below code, but it is working only one section of sceanrio , if the same value repeating it is not working. i am getting key error.

```
import re

text = []
data = []
List1=[]

with open(r'C:\user\public\test.txt') as fp:

    line = ''

    for line in fp:

        if line.startswith('Examples'):
 
            break

        text.append(line)

    text = ''.join(text)

    headers = re.split('\s*\|\s*', fp.readline())[1:-1]

    for line in fp:

        values = re.split('\s*\|\s*', line)[1:-1]

        data.append(dict(zip(headers, values)))


for d in data:
    
     List1.append(re.sub(r'\<(?P<key>[^>]*)\>', lambda x: d[x.group('key')], text))
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: yes but , if the same value repeating for example the username  and password  have different value in same text file , how can i use that .?

Comment: the exact error message is  KeyError:  "username"

Comment: That should work, though; is it possible there are stray spaces, eg. `KeyError: " username "`? Or other slight discrepancy in the field name?

Answer (score 0):

I able to fix this issue, now with multiple same header (value) can replace with corresponding values. Below the code i changed here.

```
import re

List1=[]


with open(r'C:\public\test.txt') as fp:
    with open(r'C:\public\test.txt') as file:
        file_length=len(file.readlines())
        print(file_length)
        line = ''
        fileContent=True
        counter=0
        while fileContent:
            text = []
            data=[]            
            print(counter)
            if counter >=file_length:
                print("End Of File")
                fileContent=False
                break
            for line in fp:
                counter=counter+1
                if line.startswith('Examples'): #### NEED TO CHECK FOR EVERY FEATURE FILE#####
                    break
                text.append(line)
            instructions = ''.join(text)
            headers = re.split('\s*\|\s*', fp.readline())[1:-1]
            #for line in fp:
            values = re.split('\s*\|\s*', fp.readline())[1:-1]
            counter=counter+2
            data.append(dict(zip(headers, values)))
        
            for d in data:
                List1.append(re.sub(r'\<(?P<key>[^>]*)\>', lambda x: d[x.group('key')], instructions))
                break
```